# Restore LogCat window within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I have recently started to use Android Studio v0.1.1, And i can't seem to find LogCat... Is it gone? Or if not, how can I enable it?

If it is gone, is there any way to enable something similar to log my app behavior (and mainly crashes)?

Comment: Maybe you can try to restart your computer, I fix it this way.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

I think I still can find logcat in my installation of 0.1.1

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: Note, to get it **IN A SEPARATE WINDOW** (rather than "inside" the main A.S. window, at the bottom). Use the "gear" at the extreme top right of the log cat section; select floating mode. Confusingly it then "appears to be docked" still ... just grab the bar and move it around. (If you're used to Mac, it's a little confusing.)  (Android Studio is awesome on Mac eh??)

Comment: I just see a white "logcat" box even though I've selected my device from the "Devices" window. (Android Studio 1.0.2)

Comment: With Android Studio 1.1.0 you may have to click the little icon on the top right of the Android DDMS Window, see @Manoj Behera answer two answers below

Comment: AS version is 1.2.1.1 ,but still the ctrl+6 is not working .No logcat

Comment: What about Linux?

Comment: In AndroidStudio 3.4: View->ToolWindows->LogCat.

Comment: since Android 4.2.0, there is no more shortcut for the Logcat :(

Answer (score 61):

Check if you have hidden it... Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to bring up the window and click on the button shown below 'Restore logcat view'

[image: Accessing logcat from within IDE]

Comment: Up-vote for "Restore logcat view' . The stackoverflow answer immediately hleped me without investigating into AndroidStudio help. I am using Android Studio 1.x (stable release).
I looked into stuido help, after that googled for "how to hide device log in android studio", to find hide/undo hide option.  I did hide, but could not get immediately how to undo the hide operation.

Answer (score 33):

In **Android Studio 3.4**, In the case in which Logcat does not appear in `View->ToolWindows->Logcat` (in that case `Alt+6` or `CMD+6` will also not work), the way to get the logact window is:

1. `File->Profile or debug APK`  (choose an APK)
2. Select new window or use current window.
3. Logcat is now available through the menu
   (`View->ToolWindows->Logcat`) or through `Alt+6` or
   `CMD+6`

This issue is an indication that something is not configured correctly with the Android Studio project.
The above solution can be useful:

1. As a temporary solution when there are configuration issues with the Android Studio project, that for some reason are causing Android Studio to hide the logcat window.
2. When trying to use the Android Studio logcat window for debugging an app without an Android Studio project.

Comment: I can't believe this works! What an odd bug. This happened to me in Android Studio 3.5 as well, and this method restored it. Thanks

Comment: In the end I discovered that while this method restored access temporarily, my logcat was still missing from my project's window layout. That in turn I traced to a PATHing issue with regard to how I was starting Android Studio, and once I resolved that everything was fine.

Comment: Thanks @MikeHardy, added some clarifications to the answer.

Comment: I like the clarification - I'm only responding once more in gratitude as this was the *only* thing that worked in a pinch - I really needed logcat + emulator recording *right then* and did not have time to fix my project properly yet. It is a great trick for that. Cheers!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the update cmd+6 and ant+6 not working

Comment: For me AndroidSDK wasn't configured properly, but I didn't see that error til I used this solution to pop up the logcat window!

Answer (score 20):

You can show it pressing **Alt+6**

Or...

[image: Click here!]

Comment: in your screenshot, the box that's labeled "logcat", shows no logcat even though I've properly selected the connected device and running app. I've also selected "No Filters" and still on my Nexus 5 I see no logcat

Comment: logcat stops sometimes. you may try pressing the restart icon on the left, if this does not help you may have to check that the correct device is still selected, restart adb, disconnect/connect the device, etc. :-(

Answer (score 12):

Tools-> Android -> Android Device Monitor

will open a separate window

Answer (score 11):

Android Studio 4.0.1

in my case when I press `Alt + 6` it shows logcat with no problem but when I click to dismiss it will disappear again and will not be pinned at the bottom so I pressed this little button on the bottom left of the screen then it worked. hope it will help somebody :)

[image]

Comment: That tiny button hides a lot of superpowers.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, Logcat is showing in Android Project but not in Flutter Project.

In Flutter project, click on “Event Log” tab

it will show

```
23/03/20
6:52  Frameworks Detected
Android framework is detected.
```

click “Configure”， and it will show logcat

Answer (score 7):

View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat (command + 6)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open a separate terminal and start adb with logcat.
On my (linux) system;

> ~/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat

Comment: Sorry, what? Unless there's some behind the scenes magic not explained here, this appears to be instructions on how to view the logcat output, not "how to restore the logcat window in Android Studio".

Answer (score 4):

While I would be a little late for the party, it has been a few years and new version of Studio.

Today when you encounter the bug, your logcat would not be shown, to resolve this you would need to follow these steps:

- Menu -> Build -> Make Project
- in your **settings.gradle** comment out everything and sync.
- uncomment everything and sync again.
- Menu -> Build -> Make Project
- Once the project build is done.. your Studio would be ready.

I have encountered several different bugs related to this issue, this scenario covers most of these cases.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the window was also missing and "View -> ToolWindows -> Logcat (Alt + 6)" did not even exist. Pressing ALT+6 also had absolutely no effect whatsoever.

I fixed it this way:

1. connect a device
2. start ADB via Terminal ("> adb usb")
3. stop it again (ctrl + c)
4. close the Terminal window in the bottom left window next to the Event Log (via the red X)

After closing the terminal the Logcat window appeared in the tab list and the menu entry appeared in the "View -> ToolWindows" category.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 2.3.2 you will have to click on "Android Monitor" panel at the bottom and "logcat" is a tab of this pannel. See attachment.

If you do not have this panel you will have to go to Your main menu and then View->ToolBar/ToolButtons/Statusbar/Navigationbar

[image]

Comment: This is helpful!!

Comment: I got -1 for that. This is with all my good intention to help others. I wish someone will make it right.

Answer (score 2):

**Choose "floating mode" then "Docker mode".** It's worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

When you are opening the project in the android studio instead of opening android directory open app directory

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidStudio menus click: View\Tool Windows\Android

Answer (score 1):

**way one :**

you can use bin icon in logcat
[image]

**way two:**
you can clear logcat after per lunch
Edit Configuration > Miscellaneous

check Clear log before lunch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From 2022 to forth:

On top menu:

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat
```

To show the bottom bar:

```
View -> Appearance -> Tool Windows Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly, when logcat is opened and Android Studio is switched to fullscreen mode and back, the logcat window is nowwhere to be found.

Solution:

Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Search Android Monitor tab bottom of android studio screen. Click on it. It will display a window and there is a tab call logcat. 
If you can't see Android monitor tab, click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

for me the device selection bar (or whatever it's actually called) in logcat tab doesn't show, to resolve this I had to move logcat to some other position (left/right) and move it back

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above methods does not work then try the below mechanism. Sometimes, the android studio does not show logcat options because of the project you select is not an android project. If you want to debug an APK, create an empty android project then it will start showing the `logcat` option.

Answer (score 0):

IN android studio 3.5.1  View -> Tool Windows ->Logcat

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions do not work, try to restore the default setting of Android Studio

```
File-> Manage IDE settings-> Restore Default Settings
```

Answer (score -1):

Try going to Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration

In my case it got automagically disabled

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I see the window, but no messages in it.
Only restart (studio version 1.5.1) brought the messages back.

Comment: I edited me answer to clarify. I think some users in this post have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

File ——> Project Settings ——> Facets  + Andorid  then apply
OK！

Answer (score -3):

I hope you have installed the required drivers for debugging android programs on your machine. If that is the case, when you run an application from android studio in an actual device, it will pop up a message asking to enable logcat. If you have disabled that option, then you can enable the logcat view from Window menu -> Show view -> Logcat. Next time when you run your application on actual device or in an emulator, you can see the logcat is active.

If you are not able to view it with the above solution, you can view the logcat from command line by typing

adb logcat

You can view more information from here http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html