# Logcat Bluetooth Data

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I am suffering under sound issues with my Bluetooth headset in combination with my Android 5.1.1 device. Therefore I need to debug the Bluetooth connection.
I already got some logs with `adb logcat`, but I am concerned that those logs may contain confidential data about me.

Which arguments should I use with `adb logcat`, so that the logs only contain relevant Bluetooth and headset data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get logs concerning Bluetooth. Use the logcat plugin of [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) (see [Restore LogCat window within Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/logcat-is-gone-on-android-studio) for how to open the logcat plugin) and set following filter options.

```
 Log Tag (regex): BT|luetooth|bt|Bt
 Log Level: Debug
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this , How can I get only Bluetooth specific logs ( not HCI snoop logs) on ADB