# Using LibVLC and Creation of a LibVLC object failed (Android)

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

I am working on a Android project and I want to creat a media player using the LibVLC.
To creat a media player with this lib I need to instantiate a LibVLC object.
But when I try to do that the instantiation will failed and the app will close automatically.

Here is where I creat a LibVLC object :

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity  {

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private String path;
private Bundle extras;
private static final String MEDIA = "media";
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.row);

        LibVLC lib = new LibVLC();
       // path = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("path");
   }
}
```

I am using the LibVLC get on the master branch.
So I don't understand why it failed.

Comment: There are no logcat output on Android Studio but i'm gona search if there are logcat on my smartphone

Comment: @leykan we just ask for any error log/error... Android Studio should complain and tell you something if "it fails" as you say.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/logcat-is-gone-on-android-studio).

Comment: @Takendarkk No vlc_logcat or vlc_crash...

Comment: @Takendarkk Well yes there are normal  logcat but when I click on the button that load the `MediaPlayerActivity` and so creat the `LibVLC` object, the logcat is clean I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

you should do this to make new object of LibVLC

```
LibVLC libvlc = LibVLC.getInstance();
libvlc.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);
libvlc.eventVideoPlayerActivityCreated(true);
libvlc.setSubtitlesEncoding("");
libvlc.setAout(LibVLC.AOUT_OPENSLES);
libvlc.setTimeStretching(true);
libvlc.setChroma("RV32");
libvlc.setVerboseMode(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if some of the requirements here are missing
Hopefully it will assist you .

https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample

Comment: No everithing is good, and I have build vlc-android and it works on my phone, but when I try to re-creat a LibVLC object it failed