# Logcat tab missing from debug window in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Somehow I closed the logcat tab from the debug window and now I am unable to get it back.
In Run->Configuration->Logcat I have everything checked.
I do have the logcat tab in Android Monitor window, but not in Debug.
How can I get it back?

[image]

I created a bug on on their bug-tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144525

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: If you just need any logcat output you can either use the classic android-sdk-windows\tools\monitor.bat or call "adb logcat" in commandline

Comment: For others still coming here this possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio - and there are methods there that restored the window for me (opening an apk in the Android Studio UI, to be specific)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think with the release of Android Studio 1.4 the logcat tab has been removed from the Debug view. Now I believe the only place to access it is by opening the `Android Monitor` view by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Mac.

[Release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio14beta3available) of Android Studio 1.4 Beta 3 allude to this:

> Logcat view mostly rewritten to address a number of stability and usability bugs

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because I have it on another laptop.

Comment: @Burdu hmm interesting. I am pretty positive I never closed the window, but immediately noticed it missing after upgrading to 1.4. Could the other laptop be on a pre beta 3 version of 1.4 by any chance?

Comment: I checked, it's gone here as well. Guess Google removed it. What a pity.

Answer (score 11):

In `Android Monitor` window, click the little tiny button on the top right corner.
[image]

Comment: for a light theme instead of the dark sample, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zuu4.png from 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28476685/1818089

Answer (score 6):

No one has seemed to mention this, but make sure you are inside the "android" directory and not the root directory of your project (React Native). Logcat will not display otherwise.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Click on Android Monitor at the bottom of the screen.

and then you should see there are a tab call "Logcat" next to "Memory" tab.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't downvoter, but this does not restore logcat tab to debug window. it opens it in android monitor window.

Comment: I downvoted because it seems like you didn't read my question or looked at my screenshot. This is the actual reason I created this question: not having the tab you show in your screenshot.

Comment: @Burdu Sorry, I misunderstood.
What version Android Studio you are running?

I am running 1.4 and I noticed that the debug tab that you mentioned is gone and I have to click on android monitor to see the log and it happened right after I installed 1.4 on my Mac and PC.

I think it could be 1.4 thing like AdamJohns answer.

Comment: This is a real pain because you can no longer step your code and see the logcat output.  You have to switch back and forth between the Debug window and Android Monitor window.

Comment: Thank you. Seen many threads for this, but got no answer. Finally !

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 3.5.2, Logcat can be shown from View > Tool Windows > Logcat
[image]

For some reason in a specific project, it wasn't found using this way, but I could fix it as following:

File > Project Structure > Facets > Add > Android > my_module

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I would be a little late for the party, it has been a few years and new version of Studio.

Today when you encounter the bug, your logcat would not be shown, to resolve this you would need to follow these steps:

- Menu -> Build -> Make Project
- in your **settings.gradle** comment out everything and sync.
- uncomment everything and sync again.
- Menu -> Build -> Make Project
- Once the project build is done.. your Studio would be ready.

I have encountered several different bugs related to this issue, this scenario covers most of these cases.

Comment: `Menu -> Build -> Make Project` did help. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine and it disappeared suddenly.
After nothing else worked, I ran `adb devices` to see if my device was correctly attached and TA DA.
`adb server` wasn't running and started automatically and Android Studio started to show Logcat as always.

```sh
➜ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
0030713775  device
```

Answer (score 0):

Given solutions not worked for me.

I found another solution

Click

> View-> Tool Windows -> Logcat

Then the missing Logcat tab appears again.

Android Studio IDE version: (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 8)

Answer (score -1):

press <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>.

If you still don't see it there should be a little icon in the top-right corner of the view, press that.

Comment: alt+6 switches to Android Monitor tab, where I do have it, as I mentioned in the question. I want it in the Debug tab as well, but couldn't find any option to reactivate it.

Comment: Oh, when I hide the Logcat in the Debug tab there appears an Android Robot icon in the top-right, what happens if you click that colored icon in the top-right?

Comment: That's the icon for Threads, it shows the threads tab, which I minimized.

Comment: And the Restore Layout icon on the left?

Comment: does not restore the logcat tab.

Answer (score -2):

Top Menu:

View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat

Bottom bar:

View -> Appearance -> Tool Windows Bar