# App crashes as soon as I add 2 relative layouts in a linear layout - why?

Tags: android, android-layout

So, heres the point:

I'm training up and making my first steps in android development and after I narrowed down a few errors myself, I finally came across one that I cant find the solution for.

I want to create an app that displays two pictures that split the screen in half horizontally. So I create a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation and add two `RelativeLayout`'s inside it. I compile it and the build apparently completes but as soon as the app tries to start up on my mobile (Samsung S5 Neo) it says it stopped working and I land up on my desktop again. >.< Also, before tips alike arise - yes I started a new project for testing purposes already and the same error occurs. Also, when I remove that lines of code, the app works just fine on my mobile. So, that's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="removedbecausenotyourbusiness:P">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I'd like to get to know if I can somehow get a log from my mobile as to WHY the app stopped working. Where can I get this?

EDIT: I believe I found what you were asking me for.

> 12-17 19:27:18.751 11830-11830/? E/Zygote: v2 12-17 19:27:18.751
>   11830-11830/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0 12-17 19:27:20.211
>   11830-11830/com.example.marco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.marco, PID: 11830
>                                                                                           java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 231444012 byte
>   allocation with 4182352 free bytes and 125MB until OOM
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:157)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:145)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
>                                                                                               at com.example.marco.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: add crash log so that any one identify easily

Comment: Add stacktrace. There can be thousands of reasons why it crashed, the stacktrace tells us what the issue is

Comment: my one wild guess would be using the same name for `drawable` and `id` , try to change the name of ID

Comment: But yes WHERE can I find the crash log?>.<

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284100/logcat-tab-missing-from-debug-window-in-android-studio

Comment: added the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some things you can do to fix the OutOfMemoryError from your images:

Add these lines in your AndroidManifest file under the `application` at the top:

`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

`android:largeHeap="true"`

So the very top of of your AndroidManifest will look something like this with the two added lines:

```
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"  //added
        android:largeHeap="true"             //added
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If that doesn't fix it, then you will need to compress your image files.  You can do that on a site like https://tinyjpg.com/.  It is probably just an issue of your images being too large!

Also next time you run into a problem like this, you need to use that error that you received in your crash log / stacktrace and search for the solution.  In your case, you could  have found this:  [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Comment: True.. I guess the proper way to do this would be with an image library like Picasso.

Comment: That could be one solution. Another solution can be to shrink the image in size because loading a small ic-launcher does not crash the app. So the image is probably big. Not sure what Picasso does but it could be a solution that isn't a workaround