# Log messages overload and filtering

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

The following method is called in another application (Unity3D) however, I need debugging messages to see how far that other application can reach into this program, but I cannot seem to find the couple of messages in this code snippet anywhere...

I have checked quite a few posts on where I am supposed to see the outcomes of `Log.e` and `System.out.println`, but I cannot seem to find the "filters" they refer to; i.e. how I am supposed to filter the messages.

```
public class PluginClass
{
    public static void Enable()
    {
        System.out.println("Entered the method...");

        blah...

        if ( blah... )
        {
            Log.e("app", "Entered if statement...");
        }

        blah...
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me understand where and how to fish for these two "Entered" strings in the barrage of messages that Android Studio generates Avery second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: Always use Log, though

Comment: Maybe you can need this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284100/logcat-tab-missing-from-debug-window-in-android-studio

Comment: @cricket_007 `Log` alone or `Log.e`? Also, when in `Terminal` I type `adb logcat -s Unity` I still  do not see these messages. Is there a different command for it when you say `LogCat`? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Log is a class containing 5 different methods and should be preferred over System.out. That's all. And you don't need the terminal. Read the other answers that mention Android Studio

Comment: Anyways, you're wanting `adb logcat -s "app"`, or you need to edit the code to use Unity as the tag of the log