# Setting Flutter log Levels / Flutter printing thousands of verbose lines

Tags: flutter, logging, dart, visual-studio-code

Flutter log prints thousands of verbose/spam logs.

I am trying to debug a complex app but flutter printing so much verbose that it is difficult for me to find things which i am printing myself.

Is there any way to disable Verbose?

Something like:

`Logger.level.disable('verbose')`

*My platform:*

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.42.1)
[√] Connected USB device (1 available)
```

Comment: What kind of logs are you referring to? By default, Flutter doesn't print out anything while the app is running.

Comment: @Ovidiu When I do `flutter run` or `Ctrl+F5 (Run without Debugging in VS Code)` it starts printing hundreds of line about device touch status and all kind of other stuff etc...

Comment: any new news?
it is annoying

Comment: @AminJoharinia Yes, check my answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467374/e-accessibilitybridge-virtualview-node-must-not-be-the-root-node-flutter/60562185#60562185

Comment: please see [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786515/11374545) it is not permenant but it is a good workaround

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in flutter engine which is now fixed in beta channel and soon will be released in next stable release.

You should just ignore these errors if possible otherwise change your flutter channel by:

flutter channel beta

Edit:

If you are using Android Studio then you can filter log. Deselecting any other option other than "Info" will remove unwanted log.

[image]

Comment: It's spammy for me too (years later).  Where is that dropdown?

Comment: @PaulSumpner under the logcat tab (android)

Comment: thanks, but i think the logcat tab may have gone? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32929448/1429282