# E/AccessibilityBridge: VirtualView node must not be the root node. (Flutter)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

This doesn’t affect my app, but this message always appears.

> E/AccessibilityBridge: VirtualView node must not be the root node.

Does anyone know how to tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug in flutter engine which is now fixed in beta channel and soon will be released in next stable release.

You should just ignore these errors if possible otherwise change your flutter channel by:

`flutter channel beta`

Edit:

If you are using Android Studio then you can filter log. Deselecting any other option other than "Info" will remove unwanted log.
[image]

Comment: Just upgraded to the beta channel and it didn't fix my issue. My UI opens and it freezes :(

Comment: Run `flutter clean` once.

Comment: Even after flutter clean didn't work, had to uninstall the app from the phone and then it ran smoothly :)

Answer (score 1):

uninstall the app from the phone and then restart it and tap flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

I started my app as normal, but i deleted all the content from downside all the pre code written by the flutter maybe thats why it was showing me this error but after creating a Scafold() it's gone