# Android Studio console not showing logs of application running

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running application on real android device. I want to view logs in console to figure out errors and APIs responses. But I don't know sometimes it stop showing logs in console.

Here is the screenshot of my console.
[image]

I is not showing anything after this even though I am printing in logcat.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue and how to resolve.

Comment: You can enable android support from android studio event logs tabs. as its enable Logcat for that

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your logcat and then rerun you application. ( If your logcat window tab does not show up in Android Studio you can follow this: [Logcat tab missing from debug window in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284100/logcat-tab-missing-from-debug-window-in-android-studio) )[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow my steps down below.

**Step - 1**

Goto File --> Invalidate Caches

[image]

**Step - 2**

Click to "Invalidate and Restart"

[image]

I hope this might solve your problem.

Thank you and Happy coding.