# How to view the log file in android studio?

Tags: android

I monitor an EditText using textwatcher i store every key press in a log file I want to view the data i put into the log file after running the application,but still couldn't find it how. appreciate the kindness in helping me :)

Comment: This two link helping you: [Restore Logcat window within android stadio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio) [Android stadio nothing to show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're talking about the standard Android logcat (done in code something like this `Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");`) when you say you 'store every key press in a log file', it should show up in the Android pane of Android studio (ALT+F6) as: [image]

If on the other hand, you're using some custom code for logging it would be implementation dependent (the file might even simply be stored on the test device).

Comment: Many thanks for the help !! i was able to sort what i need through the  search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Click on android studio View(ALT+V)->Tool Windows->Android Monitor

OR

**Press ALT+6**

*If the value don't display yet than restart your android studio If you want only text written in logcat than just copy it*