# Where is the logcat in Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio. And I am stuck at finding the logcat to make sure that my device is connected and is being recognized by Android Studio 3.1.4.

I can't seem to find the logcat at the bottom of the Android Studio 3.1.4. Where is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore LogCat window within Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to find **logcat** in **Android Studio**

**Android Studio** ---> **View** ----> **Tools Windows** ---> **Logcat**

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `ALT+6` on your keyboard should open it on a windows computer. On a mac it would be accordingly `CMD+6`.