# Missing Logcat in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I recently installed AS in my windows machine, I try to see my logs in Logcat but can't find/activate the Logcat.
I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio) and [there](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) but still missing my log cat:

[image: Attached the missing logcat from the Tool Windows]

How can I found and activate the Logcat?

For now I'm using the AS Console to see the logs and it is very bad so I will appreciate any solution/tip/idea.

Thanks!!

Comment: Facing the same problem here :/

Comment: yes, I don't understand it. didn't fount nothing on line and no answer here.

Comment: It often happened to me that I was unable to activate windows but the problem was that I had reduced them in size with the mouse  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Bronz, can you show me how you canceled the reduced size?

Comment: If you really do not find what is wrong try looking for: Restore Default Layout in the window menu .... obviously you will lose all the customizations of other windows as well, but if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried some recommendations of others similar posts, but it didn't work. I did this (The Event Log helped me!):

Open the Event Log and see the messages. I found a message like this:

[image]

Android Studio for some reason didn't find the Android framework configured

I clicked the link and then finally Android Studio showed me Logcat

Answer (score 1):

Click on the menu **View -> Appearance** and then check that **Tool Windows Bar** option is ticked ;)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately the `Tool Window Bars`  option is ticked :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution that made the logcat appear in my android studio was to do all the needed updates in my android studio and then press on the framework configuration option that appear in the `event log`:
[image: event log framework configuration]