# Where is the logcat window in my Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to the android studio, and I can not find the 'Logcat' window in my android studio? I can't find the window through the view option as well. Can anyone help me how to find it? Here is the screenshot of my android studio.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my android studio]

Comment: There is also the emulator missing in this picture. Do you have the newest version? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411183/missing-logcat-in-android-studio-4-1 this post might be helpfull

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but maybe you didn't install emulator and logcat during your installation of android studio? Maybe it's an option during installation or smth.

Comment: Have you tried the hotkey alt+6 or cmd+6? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio

Comment: What is the 'Problems" window? @Olli

Comment: I don't know. In my android studio there is no problems window. In your image i can see View -> Tool Windows -> Problems (Also showing at the bottom left of your image, next to TODO). Maybe check it if there are some usefull information? Did you try the answere with the event log and android framework from the question i linked?

Answer (score 1):

I think the building process was not complete. After all the building processes finished, the Logcat window showed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the app after Gradle sync then look at the bottom of the android studio logcat will be visible. if it's not visible then Try pressing Alt+6 on Windows or CMD+6 on Mac.